# Minimal one-step distance set of vertices to all vertices

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I want to find minimal set of vertices such that every vertex in this graph either in this set or connected with some vertex from this set with one edge. Is there standard name for this algorithm? It seems to me that it somehow connected to [minimal edge cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_cover) or maybe [minimal vertex cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) but I can't see how exactly they may be connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This set is called a *dominating set* and the respective algorithmic problem is NP-complete, see, for instance, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set).